# Use rebar in emacs?

Tags: emacs, erlang

There is a `defun` in .emacs to get erlang project path, how can I execute a shell-command to do the following:

```
cd *~/erlang-project-folder*
make
```

I'm using rebar to build my project, and there is a Makefile to do everything.

I can compile by overriding `erlang-compile-function`, but I'm not familiar with Emacs Lisp, please help.

Here is my .emacs:

```
(defun erlang-project-dir ()
  (let* ((src-path (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
         (pos (string-match "/src/" src-path)))
    (if pos (substring src-path 0 (+ 1 pos)) src-path)))

;; there is an error: wrong type argument: commandp
(defun my-inferior-erlang-compile ()
  (shell-command.
    (concat (concat (concat "cd" erlang-project-dir) "; make"))))

(defvar erlang-compile-function 'my-inferior-erlang-compile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of relying on directory structure, it's better to try to locate the `rebar.config` file that is in the root of your project.  This could be achieved with following code:

```
(defun my-find-rebar-root ()
  (let ((dir (locate-dominating-file default-directory "rebar.config")))
    (or dir default-directory)))
```

and after that you can use this function for compilation:

```
(defun my-inferior-erlang-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory (my-find-rebar-root)))
    (compile "make")))
```

Although, I'm not sure that the `make` is right command here - maybe it's better to use `rebar compile` instead?

P.S. I hope, that I'll find some free time, and will finish rebar support in EDE - in this case, it will be the same unified interface for work with projects.

Comment: Hi, @Alex, thank you. But `(defvar erlang-compile-function 'my-inferior-erlang-compile)` reports "wrong type argument: commandp, my-inferior-erlang-compile"

Comment: Ah, it looks like inferior-erlang-compile is used to compile buffer inside erlang environment, not to execute external shell command. I would recommend to bind some key to call compile function, for example, `(defun my-erlang-mode-hook ()   (local-set-key [f9] 'my-inferior-erlang-compile))
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook 'my-erlang-mode-hook)`

Comment: I edited the code, adding the `(interactive)` to it, so this command will be treated as command...