# How to force the erlang-compile command of emacs to search in the include directory

Tags: emacs, erlang, compiler-options

I am starting to work with emacs on some existing erlang projects. I would like to use the command erlang-compile, if possible using the short cut `C-c C-k`, but it fails because most of my projects use some .hrl files, located in an include directory, while the commands knows only the src and ebin directories *(it is the usual directory tree for erlang applications)*

I found a workaround by editing all the include directives and add the relative path to the include directory before each file name, but I don't like this, and it doesn't help if I want to compile using the options debug_info, export_all, native...

Another workaround is to use an external command, but in this case I'll loose - I guess - the link between the compilation errors and the source code.

The right way should be to pass an option list to the command (for example `[{i,"../include"},debug_info]`).

I have tried to "eval" the command using `M-:  (erlang-compile XXX)` but it fails (I dont know a bit of lisp syntax and anyway, it seems that erlang-compile has no arguments...)

I have seen this topic [Use rebar in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727051/use-rebar-in-emacs) but, as I understand the solution, it will use an external command, and it will behave like my second workaround.

is there another way or a setting to pass these arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set include paths in the `erlang-compile-extra-opts` variable. For example:

```
(setq erlang-compile-extra-opts '((i . "../include") debug_info))
```

Comment: This answers exactly to my question, but I will consider also @mpm suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not what you are looking for, but I would recommend using [EDTS](https://github.com/tjarvstrand/edts).  It consist quite few useful features, include directories can set up in `.edts` config file, and it tries to compile your code with each file save.

And just an idea. I would try using [Emakefile](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) interface. It seems standard enough and emacs/erlang integration could be using it.

Comment: EDTS seems interesting since it may solve more problems than the one I have seen so far (particularly the the parameters passed to the project node). I'll will have a look in the next days.