# how to compile erlang project with emacs

Tags: emacs, compilation, erlang

I had checked the doc of erlang-mode.

it's seem that C-c C-k, (erlang-compile) - Compiles the Erlang module in the current buffer.

just compile one file of current buffer. I wanna compile a project with rebar commond on emacs. eg. ./rebar compile

and it can display result like execute "erl -sname  -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin".

how to do this on emacs?

Comment: Perhaps this could get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727051/use-rebar-in-emacs

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for http://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this the "right" way involves inferior emacs shells and such, and isn't trivial. But you can mostly get the desired effect with these two steps:

1. At the top level of your project directory, which you can get to by visiting your `rebar.config` file, execute `M-x compile` and after hitting enter, change the compile command to `rebar get-deps compile`, then hit enter to run it.
2. Assuming the compilation in the first step succeeds, execute `C-u M-x erlang-shell` and hit enter. It will prompt you for the shell arguments, which should be

   `erl -pa deps/*/ebin -pa ebin`

   Hit enter and you'll get an erlang shell prompt, with its erlang load path properly set up for your project.

Comment: thx,I found a extension of erlang-mode,which could compile erlang project using rebar.and I should learn some elisp.